# Open Ai Transcription Api not transcripting full audio in Iphone browser

Tags: openai-api

When I send audio recordings to the OpenAI Whisper API using iphone browser, it only gives starting one or two words of that audio. It working fine on windows, mac and also on android browser but not transcipting whole audio in iphone.

Below is my code snippet
I am getting the blob of the recording and converting that blob to audio file. I checked this file by playing it and its fine because file has full audio but it does not convert to full text.

````
  const getTranscript = async (recordedBlob) => {
    try {
      const audioFile = new File([recordedBlob], "audio.mp3", {
        type: "audio/mp3",
      });
      const transcript = await openai.audio.transcriptions.create({
        model: "whisper-1",
        file: audioFile,
        response_format: "text",
      });
      return transcript;
    } catch (err) {
      return Promise.reject(err);
    }
  };```
````

Answer (score 0):

This code will work.

Save as `transcript.js`

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const FormData = require('form-data');
const fs = require('fs');

async function getTranscript(audioFilePath) {
  try {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', fs.createReadStream(audioFilePath));
    formData.append('model', 'whisper-1');

    const response = await axios.post('https://api.openai.com/v1/audio/transcriptions', formData, {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY}`,
        ...formData.getHeaders()
      }
    });

    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error.response.data;
  }
}

const audioFilePath = 'harvard.mp3';

getTranscript(audioFilePath)
  .then(transcript => {
    console.log(transcript);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });
```

##### sample audio

```
https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/pavanelisetty/sample-audio-files-for-speech-recognition?resource=download
```

[image]

Convert into .mp3 from .wav

```
https://convert.best/video/wavtomp3.htmlhttps://convert.best/video/wavtomp3.html
```

##### Set environment variable for API KEY

In Git bash

```
export OPENAI_API_KEY=[your API Key]
```

[image]

##### Install dependencies

```
npm install axios form-data fs
```

##### Run it

```
node transcript.js
```

##### Result

[image]

##### API test by Postman

Set API Key
[image]

Result
[image]